# www-data - can't create any directorys

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions

I am running Ubuntu 8.04 LTS, its my webserver (LAMP).

My web root is:

```
/var/www/website/trunk/html/
```

I created a directory for user uploads behind that, at:

```
/var/www/vault/
```

I did:

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/vault/
```

and even, bravely: (was a desperate moment)

```
chmod 777 -R /var/www/vault
```

My php script is unable to create subdirectories under:

```
/var/www/vault
```

and I need it to, I have had luck uploading a file to the directory however, I get errors like this when it tries to make directories...

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in /var/www/website/trunk/html/jquery.uploadify/uploadretro.php on line 149
File /var/www/website/trunk/html../../../../vault/4d4d3092c24be8a8dac2ec269e969446.jpg does not exist.
```

Could anyone help me out, or suggest something?

My php INI file is setup correctly allowing uploads, with a 5m size.

Any ideas?

**More Info**
The command at line 149 from the error above is:

```
mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 777, true);
```

Permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data root 4.0K Jun  3 06:04 vault
```

Comment: 0.04???  Not that it should matter, but that isn't a real version.

Comment: echo out $targetPath, is it really what you think it is?

Comment: haha ty, changed to 8.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help debug access I suggest you tothe system, and run a command like **sudo -i -u www-data**.  This will give you a shell with the same privileges as the web server.  Then simply change into /var/www/vault directory and see if you can create files and directories.

If you can create files/directories, then you problem is not permissions, and instead something is broken in your application.

Oh, and btw your path looks broken.

```
/var/www/website/trunk/html../../../../vault/
```

Pay particular attention to the **html..**.  If **html..** is the correct value, then that path is going to resolve to **/var/vault**, not **/var/www/vault**.

Comment: the sudo -i -u www-data did the trick... I missed the second group setting, should have been chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/vault/ instead of chown -R www-data /var/www/vault/

Comment: it would have been nice to get some pointers on what could be wrong in my application. I can create files/folders as www-data but my wordpress setup can't even upload files or update plugins. The permissions and ownership are all setup properly apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Restart apache.

Comment: Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in /var/www/website/trunk/html/jquery.uploadify/uploadretro.php on line 149
File /var/www/website/trunk/html../../../../vault/4d4d3092c24be8a8dac2ec269e969446.jpg does not exist.

Comment: html.. <-- is that intentional?